# How to bind single interface to multiple classes in Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Want to bind a single interface to multiple classes for Eg.

```
bind(interface1.class).to(classAbc.class);
bind(interface1.class).to(classDef.class);
bind(interface1.class).to(classGhi.class);
```

Tried this but doesn't seem to be working :

```
baseClass obj1;

obj1.add(new classAbc);
obj2.add(new classDef);

bind(interface1.class).toInstance(obj1);
```

Comment: What would you like to happen if you have `@Inject Foo(interface1 obj) { }` Would it be `classAbc`? `classDef`? How would you know?

Answer (score 2):

Have you look at `Multibinder`? 
This is example directly from [API](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/Multibinder.html)

```
 public class SnacksModule extends AbstractModule {
   protected void configure() {
     Multibinder<Snack> multibinder
         = Multibinder.newSetBinder(binder(), Snack.class);
     multibinder.addBinding().toInstance(new Twix());
     multibinder.addBinding().toProvider(SnickersProvider.class);
     multibinder.addBinding().to(Skittles.class);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Yeah i have looked at Multibinder but i cannot use it as of now. But where am I going wrong in my current implementation ? Is there any other way  to do that  ?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do something like this:

```
baseClass obj1;

obj1.add(new classAbc);
obj2.add(new classDef);

bind(interface1.class).toInstance(obj1);
```

You could, but only if your `baseClass` is of the *Composite pattern* (where objects can also act as containers for other objects). Otherwise, you'll need to provide your alternatives in another container, like a List:

```
List<Interface1> interfaceList = new ArrayList<>();

interfaceList.add(new classAbc());
interfaceList.add(new classDef());

bind(new TypeLiteral<List<Interface1>>() {}).toInstance(interfaceList);
```

Though with that solution above:

1. It won't pick up on dependencies of implementors `classAbc`, `classDef`, etc.
2. It creates all of these dependencies pre-emptively, whether they're needed or not.
3. The list is mutable, so someone else can affect the permanently-kept list.

Instead, a manual simulation of Multibinding might look like this [untested]:

```
public class YourModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override public void configure() {}

  @Provides Set<Interface1> createSet(ClassAbc abc, ClassDef def) {
    return ImmutableSet.of(abc, def);
  }

  // Provider<ClassAbc> can't usually be cast to Provider<Interface1>
  @SuppressWarnings 
  @Provides Set<Provider<Interface1>> createProviderSet(
      Provider<ClassAbc> abc, Provider<ClassDef> def) {
    return ImmutableSet.of(
        (Provider<Interface1>) abc,
        (Provider<Interface1>) def);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey,  thank you for your suggestion I will try these two solutions.

Comment: As you  have mentioned i can't cast Provider<ClassAbc> to Provider<Interface1>

Comment: Casting via a raw Provider (no type argument) should work. The right return type for the method is `List<Provider<? extends ClassAbc>>` but that's pretty awful to work with.